# Unable to override read method URI::HTTP

Tags: ruby, overriding

I am trying to stub the following:

```
uri = URI(base_url)
source = uri.read
```

I have re-written the `read` method as follows:
equire 'open-uri'

```
 module OpenURI

    module OpenRead 

      def read                                               
        return IO.read('source.html')                        
      end                                                       

    end

  end
```

But it doesn't seem to work. New to ruby and could use some pointers. I always seem to end up with

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `read' for #<URI::HTTP:0x10ac59918>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
uri = URI(base_url)
source = uri.read
```

You use the `read` method, so take a look where it is:

```
uri.method(:read).method_location
```

If you want to know where to override, go for

```
uri.method(:read).owner
```

or simply

```
def uri.read
  <your body>
end
```

Comment: Can you explain a little more on how the last part you stated (`def uri.read`) would work without stating the class or modules it came from. Or should it be `URI.read` ?

Comment: This is because when I created a different ruby file and did the above I got the following `undefined local variable or method uri' for main:Object (NameError)`

Comment: Also, when I try to override `read` I always end up with `NoMethodError: undefined method read' for #<URI::HTTP:0x10ac59918>`

Comment: `def variable.method_name` attaches to method directly to the object. So you need to have the object in the first place. Use this with care. If it's production code, take a look at the class hierarchy and a) reopen the class and define the method there b) use a module.